# Prevent readding unsubscribed users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

According to this [post](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/add-an-unsubscribed-address-back-to-a-list), Mailchimp prevents resubscription automatically.

But this is not true, and if you run a `gb.lists.subscribe(...)` on a [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) instance, it will resubscribe the user even if it was unsubscribed.

So my question: is this a Gibbon bug? A Mailchimp bug? Is this blog post wrong? Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KB article you reference is talking about functionality of the web app, not of the API. Within the API, you are perfectly capable of re-subscribing unsubscribed users and that's what Gibbon is telling MailChimp to do.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to check to see if a user is subscribed before you attempt to add them. You might be able to set the `update_existing` parameter to 'false' to have it return an error if the user already exists on the list.

Comment: Nice. I just found out that batch_subscribe respects this behaviour and doesn't reinclude unsubscribed users. They should highlight this behaviour better on their docs...